# how to get value from text file in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, comparison

I have script that make comparison between value from page php and data store in txt file, and then it will do some special code.

Content of txt file (account.txt)

```
F: user pass { expire=date; afexpire=date; email=email@gmail.com; Country=Germani; visit_from=none; ip=none; hosted=none }
F: mike fghg58g { expire=2016-05-24; afexpire=2015-5-24 17; email=mike@gmail.com; Country=uk; visit_from=none; ip=none; hosted=none }
F: adresson f5849dh9d { expire=2016-11-01; afexpire=2015-11-01 17; email=mike@gmail.com; Country=Germani; visit_from=none; ip=none; hosted=none }
```

my script

```
<?php

$user = "Mike"; // user that is inserted in page form
$email = "mike@gmail.com"; // email that is inserted in page form

$userFile = "Mike"; // user in txt file
$emailFile = "mike@gmail.com"; // email in txt file

if( $user == $userFile && $email == $emailFile ) {

    echo "The user and email is used";

} elseif( $user == $userFile && $email != $emailFile ) {

    echo "The user is used";

} else{

    // do special code

}
```

I don't know how to read file txt from path and change user and email in file to value to make comprison

```
$userFile = "Mike"; // user in txt file (account.txt)
$emailFile = "mike@gmail.com"; // email in txt file (account.txt)
```

This is my spcial script that make output in (account.txt)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $plan = $_POST['plan'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    $reciever = $_POST['reciever'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $message_user = $_POST['message'];
    $serverip = $_POST['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $to = 'sup.alphas@gmail.com';
    $parts = explode("@", $email);
    $sufemail = $parts[0];
    // $sufemail = substr(strstr($email, '@'), 1);  for domain//
    $subject_form = 'Request new account by '.$sufemail.'';
    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }
    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['user']) {
        $errUser = 'Please enter your username';
    }
    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['pass']) {
        $errPass = 'Please enter your password';
    }
    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
    if (!$_POST['country']) {
        $errCountry = 'Please enter your country';
    }
    if (!$_POST['plan']) {
        $errPlan = 'Please enter your plan';
    }
    if (!$_POST['quantity']) {
        $errQuantity = 'Please enter your quantity';
    }
    if (!$_POST['payment']) {
        $errPayment = 'Please enter your method of payment';
    }
    if (!$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) {
        $errCaptcha = 'Please enter captcha';
    }
    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errUser && !$errPass && !$errEmail && !$errCountry && !$errPlan && !$errQuantity && !$errPayment && !$errCaptcha) {
        // Start Create new account //
        $dateadd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$plan"));
        $datetry = date('Y-m-d H', strtotime("+1 day"));
        $handle = fopen('/usr/www/users/alphacz/alpha/phpm/account.cfg', 'a');
        fwrite($handle, 'F: ' . $_POST["user"] . ' ' . $_POST["pass"] . ' { expire=' . $datetry . '; afexpire=' . $dateadd . '; email=' . $email . '; Country=' . $country . '; visit_from=none; ip=none; hosted=' . $_POST['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " }\r\n");
        fclose($handle);
```

Help me, please

Thank you

Comment: How and where do you store data in the file? Since the format isn't the best.

Comment: Thank you for reply, For example (/usr/www/users/alphacz/alpha/phpm/)

Comment: I mean with which code? You can get it to work with a regex, but you can do it more easily when you write to the file in a good format in the first place.

Comment: That is ourput from other program

Comment: Okay. If you can change that then I would definitely start with saving the data in JSON format. . So here you are just trying to search if the user from the input is already in your file or not right?

Comment: i add my spicial code that make output

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Answer (score 2):

You can check a needle in a haystack which is your account file here.
username pattern is "F: {user} pass {..."
email pattern is "; email={email}; Country="
Note: You must also think that this excample check keywords incasesensitive, so
when searching and inserting, you should convert keywords to lowercase

```
$user_used = userExists('Mike');
$email_used = emailExists('mike@gmail.com');
if ($user_used && $email_used)
{
    echo 'The user and email is used';
}
elseif ($user_used) {
    echo 'The user is used';
}
else
{
    //do special code
}
function userExists($user)
{
    return (exec('grep ' . escapeshellarg('F: ' . $user . ' ') . ' {file-path}'));
}
function emailExists($email)
{
    return (exec('grep ' . escapeshellarg('; email=' . $email . ';') . ' {file-path}'));
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you @mustafayelmer your script is very good and helpful and that what i want but i need it to search user and email that are just in the same line. your script appear (The user and email is used) if it found user in the first line and email in the second line. help me please

Comment: Are there anybody to help me please?

Answer (score -2):

We could fix your current code to read from the file, but instead we first rewrite your code which writes to the file, so it will be way easier to read from the file afterwards.
<sub>(Since you only show part of the script which writes to the file I can only rewrite that part.)</sub>

**Changes**

1. JSON format for the file

   Instead of writing your data into the file in a custom format we will save the data in [JSON format](http://json.org/). You can easily work with JSON in PHP since it has [built-in functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) to work with it.
2. `$_POST` ↔ `$_SERVER` ?

   At some point you use `$_POST['REMOTE_ADDR']`, but I assume that you wanted to use `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.
3. `!$XY`

   While using `!$XY` as condition may work sometimes it isn't very practical. Since it simply negates the value and then checks if it is a truthy or falsey value and should enter the if statement or not. So I would recommend you to use [`!empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if your  input is set and is not empty.

**Code**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])){
        
        $checkPostIndices = ["name", "user", "pass", "email", "phone", "country", "plan", "quantity", "payment", "reciever", "g-recaptcha-response", "message"];
        $data = [];
        
        $errors = [];
        $errorMessages = [
                          "name" => "Please enter your name",
                          "user" => "Please enter your username",
                          "pass" => "Please enter your password",
                          "email" => "Please enter a valid email address",
                          "phone" => "Please enter your phone number",
                          "country" => "Please enter your country",
                          "plan" => "Please enter your plan",
                          "quantity" => "Please enter your quantity",
                          "payment" => "Please enter your method of payment",
                          "reciever" => "Please eneter a reciever",
                          "g-recaptcha-response" => "Please enter captcha",
                          "message" => "Please enter a message",
                         ];
        
        
        foreach($checkPostIndices as $index){
            
            if(!empty($_POST[$index])){
                $data[$index] = $_POST[$index];    
            } else {
                $errors[] = $errorMessages[$index];
            }
            
        }
        
        $data["serverip"] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
         
        $to = "sup.alphas@gmail.com";
        $sufemail = explode("@", $data["email"])[0];
        $subject_form = "Request new account by " . $sufemail;
    
                    
        if(!empty($errors)){
            
            $fileData = array_intersect_key($data, ["user", "pass", "email", "country", "serverip"]);
            $fileData["dateadd"] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data["plan"]));
            $fileData["datetry"] = date("Y-m-d H", strtotime("+1 day"));
            
            $file = file_get_contents("/usr/www/users/alphacz/alpha/phpm/account.cfg");
            $file = empty($file) ? [] : json_decode($file, TRUE);
            $file[] = $fileData;
            file_put_contents("/usr/www/users/alphacz/alpha/phpm/account.cfg", json_encode($file));

            
        }
        
    }


?>
```

---

So now after that your data should be stored in JSON like this:

```
[
    {"key":"data"}
    //...
]
```

And then you can easily use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode your file into an array, loop through the array and check if the email and user are already used.

**Code**

```
<?php

    $user = "Mike";
    $email = "mike@gmail.com";

    $file = file_get_contents("/usr/www/users/alphacz/alpha/phpm/account.cfg");
    $data = json_decode($file, TRUE);

    foreach($data as $v){
        
        if($v["user"] == $user && $v["email"] == $email){
            echo "Email and user already used";
        }
        
    }


?>
```